# Migrated Android App from Netbeans to Eclipse ADT - Will app release be considered as a "new" or "versioned" release?

Tags: android, netbeans-plugins, eclipse-adt

I previously released an Android app which was built using the Android plug-in for NetBeans.

For the subsequent updated versions, I am using the Eclipse ADT. This is due to a problem I faced with the NetBeans plug-in.

I migrated the code over and preparing to do my work. I've ensured that the package names are still the same.

My question: Will the app be treated as a "new" app given I compiled and released the app using ADT vs NetBeans? I just want to make sure that the app is considered as a updated version that is currently live...

Is there anything else I need to do to ensure that the app is still considered as a version?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Release Guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html#publishing-configure), the only things that matter are the package name and the signing certificate. Since the package name is the same, and I presume you keep your release certificate in a a separate place, the new version should be considered the same app.

Comment: It also needs to be signed with the same key to be considered the same app.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play store track app by package name and signed certificate as long as those are same you are good. Do not forget to reuse same certificate to sign.